# non-neighbor subsets of the set $S_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

can anyone help me solve this, I have no idea where to start or which way to solve this.

Let $n\ge 1$ be an integer and consider the set $S_n = \{1, 2,...,n\}$. A non-
neighbor subset of $S_n$ is any subset $T$ of $S$ having the following property: If $k$ is any element of $T$, then $k+1$ is not an element of $T$. (Observe that the empty set is a non-neighbor subset of $S_n$.)
For example, if $n = 3$, then $\{1, 3\}$ is a non-neighbor subset, whereas $\{2, 3\}$ is not a non-neighbor subset.
Let $N_n$ denote the number of non-neighbor subsets of the set $S_n$.
 Determine $N_1$, $N_2$, and $N_3$.
 Determine the value of $N_n$, i.e., express $N_n$ in terms of numbers that we have seen in class. Justify your answer. Hint: Derive a recurrence.

Comment: Start by determining $N_1,N_2$, and $N_3$. I'm sure you've already done that. What values did you get?

Comment: I really don't know how to do this. may be you can provide a bit more hint. thank you

Comment: $N_2$ is the number of non-neighbor subsets of the set $S_2.$ The set $S_2$ is $\{1,2\}$ and it has $2^2=4$ subsets. The four subsets of $S_2$ are $\emptyset,\ \{1\},\ \{2\},\ \{1,2\}.$ The empty set and the one-element sets are non-neighbor sets. The set $T=\{1,2\}$ is ***not*** a non-neighbor set because, if we take $k=1,$ then $k\in T$ and $k+1\in T.$ Therefore $S_2$ has exactly $3$ non-neighbor subsets; they are the sets $\emptyset$ and $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}.$ It follows that $N_2=3.$ Now can you determine $N_1$ and $N_3$?